# How to split the column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split the column of a dataframe as follows.
Here is the main dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df_az = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(storage_AZ)),columns =['AZ Combination'])
df_az
```

[image: AZ combination]

Then, I applied this code to split the column.

```
out_az = (df_az.stack().apply(pd.Series).rename(columns=lambda x: f'a combination').unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1))
out_az = pd.concat([out_az], axis=1)
out_az.head()
```

However, the result is as follows.

[image: out AZ]

Meanwhile, the expected result is:

[image: Expected Result]

Could anyone help me what to change on the code, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `np.ravel`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_az['AZ Combination'].apply(np.ravel))

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert column to list and `reshape` for `2d array`, so possible use `Dataframe` contructor.

Then set columns names, for avoid duplicated columns names are add counter:

```
storage_AZ = [[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],
              [[0,0,0],[0,0,1]],
              [[0,0,0],[0,1,0]],
              [[0,0,0],[1,0,0]],
              [[0,0,0],[1,0,1]]]
df_az = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(storage_AZ)),columns =['AZ Combination'])
    

N = 3
L = ['a combination','z combination']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df_az['AZ Combination'].tolist()).reshape(df_az.shape[0],-1))
df.columns = [f'{L[a]}_{b}' for a, b in zip(df.columns // N, df.columns % N)]
print(df)
   a combination_0  a combination_1  a combination_2  z combination_0  \
0                0                0                0                0   
1                0                0                0                0   
2                0                0                0                0   
3                0                0                0                1   
4                0                0                0                1   

   z combination_1  z combination_2  
0                0                0  
1                0                1  
2                1                0  
3                0                0  
4                0                1
```

If need `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.concat({'AZ Combination':df}, axis=1)
print(df)
   AZ Combination                                                  \
  a combination_0 a combination_1 a combination_2 z combination_0   
0               0               0               0               0   
1               0               0               0               0   
2               0               0               0               0   
3               0               0               0               1   
4               0               0               0               1   

                                   
  z combination_1 z combination_2  
0               0               0  
1               0               1  
2               1               0  
3               0               0  
4               0               1
```